# how can i directly access admin panel through url even if basepath is there

Tags: codeigniter

i want to make admin panel and want to access it only through url but not all pages and how can i access that page through url even if i am using the following code

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
```

i want to use above code as well as want to access only admin panel through url. can anybody help me.. i m new to codeigniter....

```
http://localhost/news/index.php/adminpanel/admin_panel_login
```

i want to access admin_panel_login as above

Comment: what problem you getting?make `adminpanel` controller and a method `admin_panel_login`

Comment: sir i want to create seperate admin folder and want to access login page of admin using url address , as in normal case if i try to access any page from url 404 error come due to baspath defined ,, so please can u tell me how to create admin panel by using admin folder

Comment: make a folder name `adminpane` and a controller `admin_panel_login` inside this folder

Comment: sir i have created this but i dont know how to set route so that when i enter the url of admin folder it access admin login form plz tell how to do that

Comment: If you create a subfolder inside your CodeIgniter, you are out of codeigniter scope for that folder... rather you can do is create your `adminpanel` controller and `admin_panel_login` and use `config\route.php` file to control your url for admin panel.